# ggplot2 second axis with custom labels after log transformation

Tags: r, ggplot2

The [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) plot below has the second x-axis with custom labels.

```
dat <- data.frame(f=seq(0.01,0.5,by=0.01),y=rnorm(50))
fPretty <- pretty(dat$f)
pPretty <- round(1 / fPretty, 2)

p1 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=f,y=y))
p1 <- p1 + geom_line(color="red")
p1 <- p1 + labs(x = "Frequency")
p1 <- p1 + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0),
                              sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks=fPretty,
                                                labels = pPretty,
                                                name="Period (1/f)"))
p1
```

I'd like to transform the x-axis to a log10 scale and plot the second axis to match:

```
p2 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=f,y=y))
p2 <- p2 + geom_line(color="red")
p2 <- p2 + labs(x = "Frequency")
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0), trans="log10",
                              sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks=fPretty,
                                                labels = pPretty,
                                                name="Period (1/f)"))
p2
```

How can I set `fPretty` and `pPretty` in `p2` to give the same effect?

I.e., in this case:

```
fPretty <- c(0.01, 0.1)
pPretty <- round(1 / fPretty, 2)
```

Do I use `scales::log_breaks()` and `scales::trans_format()`?

The aim is to specify custom tick marks for both x-axis's.

Comment: I agree. It's only an example with random data.

Comment: Also, I didn't understand your question, what :same effect" are you looking for?

Comment: Edited as per your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "the same effect".

Comment: In `p1` I use `fPretty <- pretty(dat$f)` to calculate where the tick marks will be and use that for the second axis. How can I get `fPretty` for `p2` which has the transformed axis?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify tick location on the main x-axis and also the second one.
That is add `breaks` in `scale_x_continuous` for the main x-axis.

For example,

```
fPretty <- c(0.01, 0.1)
pPretty <- round(1 / fPretty, 2)

p2 <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=f,y=y))
p2 <- p2 + geom_line(color="red")
p2 <- p2 + labs(x = "Frequency")
p2 <- p2 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = fPretty, 
                expand = c(0,0), trans="log10",
                sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks=fPretty,
                                      labels = pPretty,
                                       name="Period (1/f)"))
p2
```

[image]

**EDIT**
Using `fPretty` and `pPretty` used in `p1`.

p2 <- p2 + scale_x_continuous(breaks = fPretty, 
                              expand = c(0,0), trans="log10",
                              sec.axis=sec_axis(~., breaks=fPretty,
                                                labels = pPretty,
                                                name="Period (1/f)"))

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I've already done. How is it done dynamically?

Comment: It is "dynamical" in that you can use the same fPretty and pPretty you've used for p1. I've used the new ones since I thought you wanted to.

Comment: @user111024 see the edit. Is this what you are after?